# Jenkins auto generates wrong config for composer

Tags: jenkins, composer-php

Jenkins generated wrong config for composer in /var/lib/jenkins/.composer/config.json.

Jenkins will generate it again after I recorrect it.

I can't find any relative config in Jenkins.

Where can I setup it in Jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

Check the diff of config.json between

- your good version after manual fix
- the wrong version as regenerated by Jenkins

That will tell you exactly what is changing (for example, it could regenerate OAuth credentials)

Then check which php-related plugins you have installed (as described in "[PHP Continuous Integration Template using Composer and JenkinsCI](https://shashikantjagtap.net/php-continuous-integration-template-using-composer-jenkinsci/)"), like phing, Ruby, RVM, PHP and Rake.

See if one of them has a setting matching what is changed automatically: that would explain why your manual change is reversed.